# Unable to cut from text edit and paste into terminal

Tags: terminal, copy-paste, text-editor

Up until a day ago, I was able to cut and paste commands into terminal from text edit. This is a ongoing function as I store regularly used bash commands in text files so I can cut and paste them without needing to type them.

As of today, I can cut from text and paste to text, I can copy from terminal and paste into terminal. But I am unable to paste from text to terminal...

Where to even start figuring this out?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I never thought I would see the day.

Restarting a mac to solve a problem... this is reminiscent of when I used to use Microsoft products...